# Use a data table to mask/filter another data table in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a data table, `A` like:

```
year          location    sigma_NN_1 sigma_NN_2 sigma_NN_3
2076 43.59375_-116.78125  1.4681173   1.664289   1.735974
2077 43.59375_-116.78125  1.3798515   1.550524   1.551269
2078 43.59375_-116.78125  0.7934367   1.064248   1.177981
2079 43.59375_-116.78125  1.8235574   1.991018   2.288402
2080 43.59375_-116.78125  2.5560329   2.578093   2.589334
```

And I want to use it to mask another data table where the value of sigmas are below a threshold, lets say 2. Lets say my second data table is `B`

```
year            location       location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
2076 43.59375_-116.78125  41.15625_-90.65625 41.21875_-90.65625 41.15625_-90.65625
2077 43.59375_-116.78125  43.34375_-78.15625 43.34375_-78.21875 43.28125_-78.15625
2078 43.59375_-116.78125  41.34375_-90.78125 41.21875_-90.65625 41.53125_-73.96875
2079 43.59375_-116.78125 43.53125_-116.78125 41.34375_-90.78125 41.71875_-74.15625
2080 43.59375_-116.78125  41.34375_-90.78125 41.96875_-86.21875 41.21875_-90.65625
```

So, I want to have something like `B[A<2]`, but obviously this does not work, otherwise, I would not be here.

Any suggestions?

Expected output:

output

```
year            location       location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
2076 43.59375_-116.78125  41.15625_-90.65625 41.21875_-90.65625 41.15625_-90.65625
2077 43.59375_-116.78125  43.34375_-78.15625 43.34375_-78.21875 43.28125_-78.15625
2078 43.59375_-116.78125  41.34375_-90.78125 41.21875_-90.65625 41.53125_-73.96875
2079 43.59375_-116.78125 43.53125_-116.78125 41.34375_-90.78125                 NA
2080 43.59375_-116.78125                  NA                 NA                 NA
```

The goal is to find locations whose corresponding sigma in data table `A` is less than 2.

Comment: You may need something like `i1 <- setDT(A)[, Reduce('&', lapply(.SD, `<`, 2)), .SDcols = 3:5]; B[i1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use base R subsetting to identify the appropriate cells of `B` and replace them with `NA`. This approach requires the order of the columns in `A` and `B` to be the same.

We can use a simple conditional statement on `dfa` to find the cells with a sigma value not less than 2. Since we don't want to apply the conditional to the year and condition columns, we subset them out before applying the conditional:

```
!(dfa[-c(1,2)] < 2)
     sigma_NN_1 sigma_NN_2 sigma_NN_3
[1,]      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
[2,]      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
[3,]      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
[4,]      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE
[5,]       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
```

This returns a logical matrix we can use to subset `B` to replace values. What happens here is we subset `B` twice: first we ignore the year and location columns to get just the location columns, then we use the earlier conditional to select the rows where the matching sigma value is not less than 2 and insert `NA` into it:

```
dfb[-c(1,2)][!(dfa[-c(1,2)] < 2)] <- NA
dfb

  year            location       location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
1 2076 43.59375_-116.78125  41.15625_-90.65625 41.21875_-90.65625 41.15625_-90.65625
2 2077 43.59375_-116.78125  43.34375_-78.15625 43.34375_-78.21875 43.28125_-78.15625
3 2078 43.59375_-116.78125  41.34375_-90.78125 41.21875_-90.65625 41.53125_-73.96875
4 2079 43.59375_-116.78125 43.53125_-116.78125 41.34375_-90.78125               <NA>
5 2080 43.59375_-116.78125                <NA>               <NA>               <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that these `data.table` objects, and assuming that the rows of the 'sigma' columns in 'A' should all be less than the threshold 2.

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep("sigma", names(A), value = TRUE)
i1 <- setDT(A)[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `<`, 2)), .SDcols = nm1]
setDT(B)[i1]
```

#### Update

Based on the expected output

```
nm2 <- grep("sigma", names(A))
B[, (nm2) := Map(function(x, y) replace(x, y >= 2, NA_character_),
        .SD, A[, nm2, with = FALSE]), .SDcols = nm2][]
# year            location       location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
#1: 2076 43.59375_-116.78125  41.15625_-90.65625 41.21875_-90.65625 41.15625_-90.65625
#2: 2077 43.59375_-116.78125  43.34375_-78.15625 43.34375_-78.21875 43.28125_-78.15625
#3: 2078 43.59375_-116.78125  41.34375_-90.78125 41.21875_-90.65625 41.53125_-73.96875
#4: 2079 43.59375_-116.78125 43.53125_-116.78125 41.34375_-90.78125               <NA>
#5: 2080 43.59375_-116.78125                <NA>               <NA>               <NA>
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(year = 2076:2080, location = c("43.59375_-116.78125", 
"43.59375_-116.78125", "43.59375_-116.78125", "43.59375_-116.78125", 
"43.59375_-116.78125"), sigma_NN_1 = c(1.4681173, 1.3798515, 
0.7934367, 1.8235574, 2.5560329), sigma_NN_2 = c(1.664289, 1.550524, 
1.064248, 1.991018, 2.578093), sigma_NN_3 = c(1.735974, 1.551269, 
1.177981, 2.288402, 2.589334)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

B <- structure(list(year = 2076:2080, location = c("43.59375_-116.78125", 
"43.59375_-116.78125", "43.59375_-116.78125", "43.59375_-116.78125", 
"43.59375_-116.78125"), location_NN_1 = c("41.15625_-90.65625", 
"43.34375_-78.15625", "41.34375_-90.78125", "43.53125_-116.78125", 
"41.34375_-90.78125"), location_NN_2 = c("41.21875_-90.65625", 
"43.34375_-78.21875", "41.21875_-90.65625", "41.34375_-90.78125", 
"41.96875_-86.21875"), location_NN_3 = c("41.15625_-90.65625", 
"43.28125_-78.15625", "41.53125_-73.96875", "41.71875_-74.15625", 
"41.21875_-90.65625")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: the `i1 <- setDT(A)[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, <, 2)), .SDcols = nm1]` does not work:

`Error: unexpected '<' in "i1 <- setDT(A_sigma)[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, <"`

Comment: I meant: `Error: unexpected '<' in "i1 <- setDT(A)[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, <"`

Comment: sorry backquotes didnt copy' can u test updated code'

Comment: your output looks like


 `  year            location      location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
1: 2076 43.59375_-116.78125 41.15625_-90.65625 41.21875_-90.65625 41.15625_-90.65625
2: 2077 43.59375_-116.78125 43.34375_-78.15625 43.34375_-78.21875 43.28125_-78.15625
3: 2078 43.59375_-116.78125 41.34375_-90.78125 41.21875_-90.65625 41.53125_-73.96875`


You are missing two values one in `sigma_1` and one in `sigma_2` column, both in 4th row. are less than 2

Comment: @NoLie  Sorry, I didn't know the expected output at the time I write the answer.

Comment: No problem akrun. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Simple base R solution:

```
B[-(1:2)][A[-(1:2)]>=2] <- NA
```

Select all columns except first and second `B[-(1:2)]`.

Then use the vectorized logical expression `A[-(1:2)]>=2` to set the correct elements to `NA`.

Results:

```
  year            location       location_NN_1      location_NN_2      location_NN_3
1 2076 43.59375_-116.78125  41.15625_-90.65625 41.21875_-90.65625 41.15625_-90.65625
2 2077 43.59375_-116.78125  43.34375_-78.15625 43.34375_-78.21875 43.28125_-78.15625
3 2078 43.59375_-116.78125  41.34375_-90.78125 41.21875_-90.65625 41.53125_-73.96875
4 2079 43.59375_-116.78125 43.53125_-116.78125 41.34375_-90.78125               <NA>
5 2080 43.59375_-116.78125                <NA>               <NA>               <NA>
```